# why is this not printing

Tags: string, variables, printing

This is from Ken Lambert's "Fundamentals of Python":

```
{
sum=0
while True:
    data = input('enter a number or just enter to quit: ')
    if data == "":
        break
    number = float(data)
    sum += number
print("the sum is", sum)
}
```

error message:

```
    data = input('enter a number or just enter to quit: ')
  File "<string>", line 0

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: You don't put curly braces around code blocks in Python.

Comment: I removed them and they still are not printing

Comment: Can't you see "enter a number or just enter to quit:" now ? (printed)

Comment: i can enter numbers but when i press enter to quit i get "Traceback (most recent call last):

    data = input('enter a number or just enter to quit: ')
  File "<string>", line 0
    
    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Process finished with exit code 1"

Comment: The `input` function is used for reading and evaluating Python expressions. An empty line is not a valid Python expression. You should use a function that just reads a line without trying to execute it as code.

Comment: Try using `raw_input` instead.

Comment: it is not an empty line, it is an empty string (according to the book).

Comment: But an empty string is not a valid Python program.

Comment: raw_input worked. thanks! why did this work?

Answer (score 1):

[Use `raw_input` rather than `input`. The description of](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) `input` begins with:

> Equivalent to `eval(raw_input(prompt))`

You're getting an error because `eval("")` reports a syntax error, because there's no expression there; it gets EOF immediately.

On the other hand, the description of [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) says:

> The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that.

Since you want the string that the user typed, rather than the evaluation of an expression, this is the function you should use.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that the example code was intended for Python 3.x, and the OP is running it in a Python 2.x interpreter.

Comment: yes that is correct I am using 2.x. and thanks Barmar!

Answer (score 0):

The error you provided is because you used input, which tries to execute the text from stdin as python code https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input. I've provided some fixes below.

```
sum=0
while True:
    data = raw_input('enter a number or just enter to quit: ')
    if len(data) < 1:
        break
    number = float(data)
    sum += number
print("the sum is %f" % sum)
```

Comment: Might also be worth it to put a `try/except ValueError` loop as well. However that is up to user preference if they want to continue on bad user input.

Comment: Agreed, but I went for simplicity (and left validation to OP)

Comment: Mixed whitespace would produce an `IndentationError`, not a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: the error message says that the syntax error is in `<string>`, which is the string being processed by `input()`, not the script itself.

Answer (score 0):

I found that you have a syntax problem with your code.  If you want to to put data in a variable you should use that:

```
variable = raw_input("Please enter ____")
```

Therefore you should replace line 4 to:

```
data = raw_input('enter a number or just enter to quit: ')
```